# Format ACF and PACF plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to have 2 side-by-side plots of the ACF and PACF functions in R (please see code below). Now, I want to line up the significant levels in each plot. In this case the ACF y-axis needs to shift up, or the PACF y-axis must shift down. Is there an argument in either the PACF or ACF functions to achieve the desired plot? Thank you for your help!

```
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)

getSymbols("TB3MS",src="FRED")
TB3MS <- TB3MS['1960::2002']

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
acf(TB3MS)
pacf(TB3MS)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple, you can play with the ylim of your graph

Check this:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
acf(TB3MS, ylim=c(-0.2, 1))
pacf(TB3MS, ylim=c(-0.2, 1))
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

If you want to automate it, you may calculate the lowest value of the two graphs

```
lower_ylim <- min(min(acf(TB3MS, plot=F)$acf), min(pacf(TB3MS, plot=F)$acf))
```

Comment: oh! thank you, i didn't realize acf is really plot.acf. really appreciate it, you saved me hours!